# Android. Twitter и LinkedIn шаринг без логина

Tags: android, twitter, linkedin

В Facebook есть sharing dialog, в google plus также есть какойто там интент. На примере фейсбука: можно создать sharingDialog и при вызове он проверить наличие утстановленого приложения от фейсбука, если его не будет то он откроется в web view, и пользователь будет вводить свои данные ВНЕ моего приложения, мне не нужно от соц сети данные и поэтому я хочу вынести аутентификацию. Так вот! Есть такая возможность для twitter и LinkedIn?

Comment: Эммм... Шта? Я думаю вы сами с трудом понимаете, что вам нужно. Попробуйте немного подумать и потом переписать вопрос. Просто какой шаринг без логина? Вы о чем вообще? Шаринг в космос?

Comment: Прочтите, Вы, внимательнее, зачем так агресивно показывать что вы не поняли вопроса?) Давайте на пальцах. есть приложение, в нем есть кнопка share, когда нажимаете на эту кнопку открывается установленное приложение фейсбука, или твитера или линкеда и уже там вы произведете логин и откроеться форма с теми данными что вы передали из свогоего прилодения, суть в том, что бы не добавлять аутентификацию в приложение, так как она не надобна, мне не нужна информация профиля или регистация через соц сети в приложении, в фейсбуке такая возможность есть в гугл + также.

Comment: Если и так не понятно вот вам ссылки - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android, https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/

Comment: посмотрев ссылки увидете, что там нет аутентификаци, не ид приложения или секретов приложения

Comment: Вы пробовали Intent.ACTION_SEND для рассылки или такой вариант не подходит? Просто у твиттера есть Twitter Kit, но там с секретами и циферками, так же и в  Linkedin

Comment: Intent.ACTION_SEND работает круто, если приложение установлено, но вот когда его нет оно не работает).  Я уже так же сделал вывод что с твитером и линкедом так не пройдет.

Comment: Я думал вы уже давно сделали и забыли... Вопрос же распространенный,  стоит немного погуглить http://stackoverflow.com/a/21186753/2021362 
в аналог можно найти и на Linkedin, но не советую таким подходом пользоваться, т.к. если что-то поменяют в урле - все развалится. Если нет приложения - пусть ставит.